# Jquery: Attach change event to children

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form id="duration">
    <label for="change-chart-type-24H" >
        <input style="display:none;" name="chart-type" id="change-chart-type-24H" type="radio" value="24H">24H</label>
    <label for="change-chart-type-7D" >
        <input style="display:none;" name="chart-type" id="change-chart-type-7D" type="radio" value="7D" checked="true">7D</label>
    <label for="change-chart-type-30D" >
        <input style="display:none;" name="chart-type" id="change-chart-type-30D" type="radio" value="30D">30D</label>
</form>
```

I want to attach change() event to the radio buttons.

When I try like this

```
$('input[type=radio][name="chart-type"]').change( function() {
});
```

It attaches the change() event only to the first radio button.

How can change the `jQuery selector` to attach the change() event to all the radio buttons?

*Note: When I console `$('input[type=radio][name="chart-type"]')` in the browser it shows only the first radio button.*

Comment: not sure how that would be possible.... Maybe `$` is not jQuery.... And you are using chrome's `$` which is short cut for `doument.querySelector`

Comment: All the radio buttons have the same name, that should attach the event handler to all of them.

Comment: But is is not happening, only first one is shows in the console `$('input[type=radio][name="chart-type"]')`

Comment: https://jsbin.com/bejebozupa/1/edit?html,css,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: if radio buttons generated dynamically then me be try `$(document).on('change','input[type=radio][name="chart-type"]', function() {
alert(1)
});`

Comment: your code works perfectly

Comment: just tested it, works here as well - https://codepen.io/Dwza/pen/MWemqMm?editors=1010

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an ID or a class to all the radio buttons and select the buttons using that. For instance:

```
<label for="change-chart-type-24H" >
        <input class="radio-button" style="display:none;" name="chart-type" id="change-chart-type-24H" type="radio" value="24H">24H
</label>
<label for="change-chart-type-7D" >
        <input class="radio-button" style="display:none;" name="chart-type" id="change-chart-type-7D" type="radio" value="7D" checked="true">7D
</label>
```

and in your Jquery selection, you can use something like this:

```
$(".radio-button").change( function() {
});
```

Also, make sure that all your jQuery is inside a `$(document).ready(funciton(){})`

I tried it on my own and it seems to work. Here is what I have: https://codepen.io/habdeltawabae/pen/poyKQEP